# Serverless Error ----- Invalid character in entity name Line: 0 Column: 382 Char: = while deploying lambda function in ap-south-1 region

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

```
serverless: Excluding development dependencies…
Serverless: Injecting required Python packages to package…
Serverless: Creating Stack…
Serverless: Checking Stack create progress…
CloudFormation - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::CloudFormation::Stack - test-serverless-dev
CloudFormation - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::S3::Bucket - ServerlessDeploymentBucket
CloudFormation - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::S3::Bucket - ServerlessDeploymentBucket
CloudFormation - CREATE_COMPLETE - AWS::S3::Bucket - ServerlessDeploymentBucket
CloudFormation - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::S3::BucketPolicy - ServerlessDeploymentBucketPolicy
CloudFormation - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::S3::BucketPolicy - ServerlessDeploymentBucketPolicy
CloudFormation - CREATE_COMPLETE - AWS::S3::BucketPolicy - ServerlessDeploymentBucketPolicy
CloudFormation - CREATE_COMPLETE - AWS::CloudFormation::Stack - test-serverless-dev
Serverless: Stack create finished…
Serverless Error ----------------------------------------
Invalid character in entity name
Line: 0
Column: 382
Char: =
Your Environment Information ---------------------------
Operating System: linux
Node Version: 14.16.0
Framework Version: 2.31.0
Plugin Version: 4.5.2
SDK Version: 4.2.2

**Edit: Adding Serverless.yml below**
service: testserverless
frameworkVersion: '2'
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.6
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221
  region: ap-south-1
functions:
  myfunc:
    handler: main_nise_plus_train.train_handler
    timeout: 30
custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux
    zip: true
    slim: true
plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
```

serverless.yml

The same deployment doesn’t give this error in other aws regions and deployment is successful. Any resolution for this error? Please let me know how to resolve.
Thank you

Comment: Could you please post the full log trace from CloudFormation? Serverless normally outputs the link to the full logs for the CloudFormation creation process at the bottom of the output during a failure.

Additionally, this could be caused by something in your serverless.yml file. Could you post that file with sensitive information removed/redacted?

Thanks!

Comment: 1.The link to full logs is not getting generated. 
2. If this was because some issue with serverless.yml then the same issue should arise in every region. It fails only in ap-south-1. With same yml file the deployment is successful in other regions which is surprising. I have posted the serverless.yml in the edit. Please let me know if there is some mistake. Thanks.